# Run jQuery function on ready and resize

Tags: jquery, resize, onload

I wrote the next functions and would like to combine them to make the code better. Basically, what it does is to get the width from a div and apply it to the height to make the div square and responsive:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var square = $(".responsive-col").width();
    $(".responsive-col").height(square)
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var square = $(".responsive-col").width();
    $(".responsive-col").height(square)
});
```

I've tried an approach that I found here but it didn't work. This is what I tried with no success:

```
function square() {
    var imageWidth = $(".responsive-col").width();
    $(".responsive-col").height(imageWidth);
});

$(document).ready(square);
$(window).on('resize', square);
```

I also tried this one with no success either:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    square();
    $(window).on('resize', square);
});

function square() {
    var imageWidth = $(".responsive-col").width();
    $(".responsive-col").height(imageWidth);
});
```

Could somebody tell me what I did wrong or give me a solution?

I've created a demonstration with the original code here: https://jsfiddle.net/tj8Lu30e/3

Comment: _"it didn't work"_ Can describe "it didn't work" ? , Can include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Different events can't be triggered at the same time.

Comment: @RomanC that is not true

Comment: Try it on window.load() see any difference ?

Comment: @Rudi What is not true? Are you kidding me?

Comment: I've created a demonstration with the original code here: https://jsfiddle.net/tj8Lu30e/3/

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one `.responsive-col` element, this is one way to reuse the `square` function. It caches the elements first, so jQuery only has to query the DOM once to find the elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/hu0t1gLL/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $responsiveCol = $('.responsive-col');
    var $overlay = $('#overlay');

    function square() {
        var width = $responsiveCol.width();
        $responsiveCol.height(width);
        $overlay.css({ width: width, height: width });
    }    

    square();

    $(window).resize(square);

    $overlay
        .mouseenter(function() {
            $overlay.stop(true, false).animate({opacity: "0"}, {duration: 300});
        })
        .mouseleave(function() {
            $overlay.stop(true, false).animate({opacity: "0.8"}, {duration: 300});
        });

});
```

Comment: This is definitely not a solution.

Comment: Well it is. Why do you think it's not?

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hu0t1gLL/1/ - the code is corrected to pretend there is only one `.responsive-col`, because the related element with ID `#overlay` must be unique